# SharedPreferance lost between activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this code in 1 activity :

```
  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Log.e("Facebook Session","Invalid");
                //do facebook authorize...
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("Facebook Session","valid");
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent (MainActivity.this, FacebookFriendsListActivity.class);

            MainActivity.this.startActivity(nextActivity);
        }
```

Which does as excpeted, showing session as "valid" and starting new activity,
But in the new activity i use exact same code, though the data returning from the SharedPreferance is null. the other activity is a `ListActivity` if it makes any difference.

This is the code in 2nd activity :

```
            Log.e("Login","entered func");
          mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            if(access_token != null) {
                Log.e("acces_token","Isn't null");
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if(expires != 0) {
                Log.e("expires","Isn't null");
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }
```

As you could probably guess, no Log has been made, besides the one showing the method is being entered.
Help any one can help me solve this bizzare problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using **activity private** preferences. See the documentation of the method you are using `getPreferences` . Private to THAT activity!

Use this instead:

```
getSharedPreferences("some_identifier", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Thanks man it works now, didn't know about the shared preference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the link to documentation, but my experiences:

```
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

...
mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

You can call `getApplicationContext()` inside a context.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences are saved per Activity; if you want to share them between activities you have to pass a this-reference from the first to the second Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The preferences returned by `getPreferences` are exclusive to the `Activity` it's being called in. Use [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) instead for preferences global to your app.